# Запрос с order by

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

Всем привет, пытаюсь данный запрос

```
String query = "select * from clippersql.vp44150sql where kiz like'" + kiz + "%'" + " limit " + 100 + " offset " + (page - 1) * 100;
```

сделать с `order by`

```
String query = "select * from clippersql.vp44150sql order by osdch_t where kiz like'" + kiz + "%'" + " limit " + 100 + " offset " + (page - 1) * 100;
```

но выдает ошибку

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "where"   Позиция: 54

Подскажите что не так, в sql новенький, БД postgre

Comment: order by должен быть в после where как минимум

Comment: сделал так - `String query = "select * from clippersql.vp44150sql where kiz like'" + kiz + "%'" + " limit " + 100 + " offset " + (page - 1) * 100 + " order by osdch_t";` пишет теперь - ERROR: syntax error at or near "order"   Позиция: 78

Comment: LIMIT/OFFSET идёт после ORDER BY. Посмотрите наконец https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - порядок секций менять НЕЛЬЗЯ.

Comment: Попробуйте впихнуть order by между where и limit

Comment: спасибо получилось))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В SQL важен порядок: order by в этом случае должен идти сразу за where.

```
String query = "select * from clippersql.vp44150sql where kiz like'" + kiz + "%' order by osdch_t limit " + 100 + " offset " + (page - 1) * 100;
```